# Yii PHPUnit With Selenium

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, yii, phpunit

I'm having some trouble starting automated tests with Yii, PHPUnit and Selenium
I've set up Selenium and PHPUnit and when i run phpunit . I get this error:

```
    Warning: include(PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php): failed to open stream: No such 
file or directory in path_to/framework/YiiBase.php on line 427

    Warning: include(): Failed opening 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php' for inclusion 
(include_path='.:') in path_to/framework/YiiBase.php on line 427
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable    
must be set by the phantomjs.binary.path capability/system property/PATH variable; for more 
information, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki. The latest version can be downloaded 
from http://phantomjs.org/download.html
```

I have Selenium RC running in background. I also have PHPunit folder inside tests folder, with Story and selenium extensions.

My code looks looks like this

```
define('TEST_BASE_URL','http://some_local_url/');
class WebTestCase extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    /**
     * Sets up before each test method runs.
     * This mainly sets the base URL for the test application.
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->setHost('localhost');

        $this->setPort(4444);
        $this->setBrowserUrl(TEST_BASE_URL);
    }
}

class SiteTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->open('');
        $this->assertTextPresent('Welcome');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include your `index-test.php`, or the entry script for `some_local_url`?

Comment: Do I need a index-test.php? Might be the problem?! What should go in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Selenium server needs phantomjs (thank you captain obvious), to run correctly. I simply put the server .jar file in the same folder as phantomjs binary and the tests were running correctly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't configured the path to the framework in your test entry script (`index-test.php` by default) properly. You should also set your config file here. Without this your tests run with the same settings (databases, sessions) as your application.

This is the content of `index-test.php` for the demo blog : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/demos/blog/index-test.php

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the bootstrap file for test application.
 * This file should be removed when the application is deployed for production.
 */

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/test.php';

// remove the following line when in production mode
// defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Comment: I did this but still no luck, getting the same errors :s What should I have in my config?